# SharePoint 2013 New List Experience Alternating Row Color

Tags: css, sharepoint

In SharePoint 2013/2016 they rolled out what they call the "new list experience" which is a different view from the traditional SharePoint table-based list tables because it uses DIVs instead. In the table-based lists we targeted the class .ms-alternating to alternate row colors and make large lists easier to read. In the new list experience nested DIVs for each row all have the class .ms-List-cell, without any alternating row options. It's just DIV on top of DIV.

I've found JavaScript which uses the odd/even functions in a table, but since this isn't a table that doesn't work either.

I could switch back to the traditional list style and use the Shaded list style setting, but this removes the have “allow multiple selections” quick filters in the column headings, something we'd rather keep.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: I don't know much about sharepoint, but have you tried css' `:nth-child(odd/even)` psuedo selector?

Comment: I attempted to, but since there are several nested DIVs I couldn't get it targeted correctly. I'm going to keep chugging at it, but for now I have an alternative solution to switch back to classic SharePoint view and use the alternate row class in the tables.

My real problem was that the column header filters change functionality depending on which style view you select. I needed to allow multiple selections but the Shaded style changed the filter options. SP Online keeps it interesting that's for sure..